# How do I workaround this error ? You can't specify target table my table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to convert my select query into a update query, it has aliases..

```
Update pads set RemoveMeDate = '1999-01-01 00:00:00' where padid in (
SELECT old_table.padid
FROM `jules-fix-reasons`.`pads` AS old_table
JOIN `jules`.`pads` AS new_table ON old_table.padid = new_table.`PadID`
WHERE new_table.RemoveMeDate <> '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
AND old_table.RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I've tried removing the aliases, but that doesn't help :(

EDIT - Richard, screen shot
[image]

Comment: look at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

Comment: Yeah I saw that it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update pads 
set RemoveMeDate = '1999-01-01 00:00:00' 
where padid in (SELECT padid FROM 
                ( SELECT old_table.padid 
                 FROM `jules-fix-reasons`.`pads` AS old_table JOIN 
                      `jules`.`pads` AS new_table ON old_table.padid = new_table.PadID
                 WHERE new_table.RemoveMeDate <> '2001-01-01 00:00:00' AND old_table.RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00') a)
```

Comment: That didn't work, even with the extra bracket. Did you miss something after a ?

Comment: Ooops, try that. Edited in place.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''jules-fix-reasons'.'pads' AS old_table JOIN 'jules'.'pads' AS new_table ON old_' at line 1

Comment: Try that. Edited in place again. I don't have your tables, etc. so I can't check all the syntax...

Comment: A is the alias for the subquery within the subquery I added. Basically I just wrapped your subquery in another subquery. It's a workaround for the way MySQL translates the SQL for update statements with subqueries.

Comment: Hmmm, I've added a screen shot with your last query, not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jules: I fixed his answer, he was mixing up single quotes and backticks in the table names. Could you see if his solution works now?